# Where can I find a comprehensive list of DOSbox shortcut commands?

Tags: shortcuts, dosbox

I've got a shortcut linked to **dosbox.exe** named:

```
dosbox - START.lnk
```

in it I have:

```
D:\_DOSBox\dosbox.exe -conf mydosbox.conf -noconsole -c
```

However, I only got it because I looked into some of the shortcuts from various games. I can't seem to find a comprehensive shortcut commands.

`-noconsole` is self-explanatory, but what's `-c` ? What else is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the DOSBox wiki: http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Usage